# Крашится программа для парсинга текстового файла с++

Tags: c++, парсер

Написала программу для парсинга текстового файла типа nmea на с++, компилируется без ошибок, ума не приложу в чем может быть проблема, тк недавно только начала изучать данный язык..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* TODO (#1#): Cоздать класс времени */
/* TODO (#2#): Настроить работу поиска SNR в зависимости от к-ва спутков */
/* TODO (#3#): Сделать периоды работы от off до on */
/* TODO (#4#): Проверка контрольной суммы */

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    float* t0 = NULL;
    int tount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int k;

    ifstream logs_("C:/Users/Olya/Desktop/logGLO.txt");
    ofstream tout("outLOGTime.txt");
    ofstream pout("outLOGPot.txt");

    if (logs_.is_open())
    {
        while (!logs_.eof())
        {
            k = 0;
            logs_ >> line;
            if (line.substr(0, 6) == "$GPGGA")
            {
                if (t0)
                {
                    tout << atof(line.substr(7, 10).c_str()) - *t0 << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    t0 = new float;
                    *t0 = atof(line.substr(7, 10).c_str());
                }
                tount++;
            }
            else if (line.substr(0, 6) == "$GPGSV")
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                    if (line.at(i) == ',')
                        k++;
                if (k = 7)
                {
                    pout << atof(line.substr(0, 2).c_str()) << endl;
                }

                for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                    if (line.at(i) == ',')
                        k++;
                if (k = 11)
                {
                    pout << atof(line.substr(0, 2).c_str()) << endl;
                }

                for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                    if (line.at(i) == ',')
                        k++;
                if (k = 15)
                {
                    pout << atof(line.substr(0, 2).c_str()) << endl;
                }

                for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                    if (line.at(i) == ',')
                        k++;
                if (k = 19)
                {
                    pout << atof(line.substr(0, 2).c_str()) << endl;
                }
            }
            else if (line.substr(0, 6) == "$GLGSV")
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                    if (line.at(i) == ',')
                        k++;
                if (k = 7)
                {
                    pout << atof(line.substr(0, 2).c_str()) << endl;
                }

                for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                    if (line.at(i) == ',')
                        k++;
                if (k = 11)
                {
                    pout << atof(line.substr(0, 2).c_str()) << endl;
                }

                for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                    if (line.at(i) == ',')
                        k++;
                if (k = 15)
                {
                    pout << atof(line.substr(0, 2).c_str()) << endl;
                }

                for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                    if (line.at(i) == ',')
                        k++;
                if (k = 19)
                {
                    pout << atof(line.substr(0, 2).c_str()) << endl;
                }
            }

            logs_.close();
            delete t0;
            tout << "K-vo Zna4eniy -- " << tount << endl;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "File is not open" << '\n';

    tout.close();
    pout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2. То что кидается в глаза `if(k = 7)` - неверная запись. Верная запись `if(k == 7)`

Comment: используйте отладчик и также укажите на какой строке крашится

Comment: 1. Учитесь пользоваться отладчиком, найдите строку в которой или после которой происходит сбой, и укажите где именно сбой. Желательно так же указать значение связанных локальных/глобальных переменных, которые задействованы в месте где произошёл сбой. Ваш код специально тестировать не будет.

Comment: @nick_n_a `if(k == 7)` спасибо, исправила, никогда раньше не пользовалась отладчиком. Сейчас запустила его в среде разработке Dev-C++ и он тоже вылетел с ошибкой. Тогда я попробовала онлайн дебагер, вот что он мне выдал
```
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000e4e3c0 ***                                   
Aborted (core dumped)
...Program finished with exit code 134                                                                                
Press ENTER to exit console.

```

Comment: Нашла ошибку: ``` delete t0; ``` была лишней, повторно освобождала память, теперь программа не крашится, а просто работает неправильно, но уже по другим причинам :)